# Zoom/pan/tilting webcam

Tags: webcam

I have a logitech camera and I need a way to zoom the image. I tried lots of options but none game me that option. Can someone help? I would be more confortable with CLI tools by the way.

Comment: The camera model is HD c270

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution is to make a virtual camera that shows part of the image of the real camera.

### Kernel module

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

To activate virtual camera device, insert the module into kernel:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

To deactivate:

```
sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
```

When module is active, it creates one more /dev/video device (for me it was `/dev/video1`).

To insert the module on boot, add a config file with the module name to `/etc/modules-load.d/`.

### Transformation

Assuming that the main camera is on `/dev/video0` and 200 pixels should be chopped from each side of the image:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videocrop top=200 left=200 right=200 bottom=200 ! v4l2sink
```

To see the result from the virtual camera:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! xvimagesink
```

And it is usable as an ordinary v4l2 camera device in qTox, for example.

Tested on C270.